# Digital self-signed certification update expiry date

Tags: java, certificate, keytool, digital-certificate

I have a self-signed digital certificate created using java `keytool` command.
Can I update only the expiry date of the keystore file, without creating new keystore?
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the validity period without resigning the certificate. However, you don't have to create a new keystore. Just sign the certificate again with new expiration date and replace it in the keystore.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Can you help me with keytool commands for re-signing the certificate and replace it in keystore ?

Comment: I looked into the keytool command but I wasn't able to find a way to sign the certificate again. How can I do it?